# Why am I getting a 403 forbidden error when getting other user's calendar in a Microsoft Graph API call?

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api

I ran into a problem with getting the conference room calendar in Microsoft Graph.

1. By first I tried to simulate the request with Microsoft Explorer in a way:

   ```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/conference_room_ID_or_name/events
   ```

And it is getting 403 Forbidden - "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.".
Actually, I got the needed permissions set by admin: Calendars. Read, Calendars.ReadWrite. I can add such a calendar manually to my outlook web page and I see all the events. But getting such a request in a Microsoft Explorer is not working.

I also registered my app in Microsoft Azure with granted permission to be sure.

2. I also tried another approach:

   ```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/shared_calendar_id_in_my_account/calendarView
   ```

And it's getting the events, but not all of them - I see for sure these created by me in a conference room, but I couldn't get all the events created by other people - for example reoccurring one's.

I'm not sure if it's a permissions issue or any known (or not) issue with Graph such like:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#accessing-a-shared-calendar
```

Comment: Hey, are you logging in and putting the most recent access token? Maybe the token changed during permission change and you should refresh it with refresh token or by logging in again?

Comment: go to  AAD>App registrations>your app>API permissions   Provide screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You have granted the wrong permissions. For the `/users` context, no user is logged in. You need to grant application permissions.

[image]

List `events` of other users:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events
```